# Differentiate matrix product with respect to vectorized form

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am very new to matrix calculus, but I can't seem to figure this out. Suppose $\pmb{X}$ is a non-square $m 
\times n$ matrix and $\pmb{Y}$ is a symmetrical positive definite $n \times n$ matrix that is not a function of $\pmb{X}$. I need to differentiate:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathrm{vec}\left( \pmb{X}  \right)} \mathrm{vec}\left( \pmb{X} \pmb{Y} \pmb{X}^{\top}  \right)
$$
which should lead to a $n^2 \times nm$ matrix I think. My first thought was to make use of $\mathrm{vec}\left( \pmb{X} \pmb{Y} \pmb{X}^{\top}  \right) = (\pmb{X} \otimes \pmb{X}) \mathrm{vec}(\pmb{Y})$, but post-multiplying $\mathrm{vec}(\pmb{Y})$ with any result of differentiating $\pmb{X} \otimes \pmb{X}$ with respect to $\mathrm{vec}\left( \pmb{X}  \right)$ doesn't seem to give a reult of the right dimensions.

Comment: Differentiating with respect to a function seems to be fraught with issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the vector
$$\eqalign{
w &= {\rm vec}(XYZ) \cr
 &= (Z^TY^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(X) &= (Z^T\otimes X)\,{\rm vec}(Y) &= (I\otimes XY)\,{\rm vec}(Z) \cr
 &= (Z^TY^T\otimes I)\,x &= (Z^T\otimes X)\,y &= (I\otimes XY)\,z \cr
}$$
and its differential
$$\eqalign{
dw &= (Z^TY^T\otimes I)\,dx + (Z^T\otimes X)\,dy + (I\otimes XY)\,dz \cr
}$$
Now assume $Y$ is constant and $Z=X^T$, i.e. 
$$dy=0,\quad dz=K\,dx$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the vec-operation.

Substituting this into the differential expression yields
$$\eqalign{
dw &= \Big(\big(XY^T\otimes I\big) + \big(I\otimes XY\big)K\Big)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} &= \big(XY^T\otimes I\big) + \big(I\otimes XY\big)K \cr
}$$

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: Just a question, shouldn't the + signs in the first three lines be = signs instead?

Comment: You're absolutely correct!  I've replaced them with = signs.